# How to separate words from numbers using \w+ (not using A-Ba-b or \d)?

Tags: python, regex, ocr

I extracted text from a file using OCR (optical character recognition) and I got this string:

```
Lisboa                       187      
      Santo Tirso                  8\n\n        Porto                        137            Vila do Conde
 8\n\n        Maia
   119            Penafiel
       7\n\n        Vila Nova de Gaia   
         83             Portimão        
             7\n\n        Oliveira de Azeméis          18             Évora
         5\n\n
```

I want to get a list of tuples, being each tuple ("name of the city", "following number"), like this:
[("Lisboa", "187"), ("Santo Tirso","8"), ("Porto", "137"), ...]

I wrote this expression:
r"([A-ZÁÉÍÓÚ][\w()-\ ]+) ([\d]+)"

because the name of the cities may include tildes and spaces, but I get ("name of a city    following number    name of other city", "number following the second city"), like this:
("Lisboa                       187      Santo Tirso", "8").

So: I wanna use \w+ but exclude all digits from the first group (which will be the first element of the tuple). How should I do this?

Comment: Maybe you wanna use e.g. `\w+?` to do non-greedy matching?

Comment: \w+ does not allow spaces. For example "Santo Tirso", "Vila Nova de Gaia" or "Oliveira de Azeméis"...

Comment: You show 10 newlines (`\n`) in your string but it actually contains  17. Did you add some when formatting your question? If so, they should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You might use

```
import re

junk = """
Lisboa                       187      
      Santo Tirso                  8

        Porto                        137            Vila do Conde
 8

        Maia
   119            Penafiel
       7

        Vila Nova de Gaia   
         83             Portimão        
             7

        Oliveira de Azeméis          18             Évora
         5


"""

rx = re.compile(r'\b(?P<city>(?:[A-Za-zéÉã]+\s)+)\D+(?P<number>\d+)')

cities = [(m.group('city').strip(), m.group('number'))
          for m in rx.finditer(junk)]

print(cities)
```

Which yields

```
[('Lisboa', '187'), ('Santo Tirso', '8'), ('Porto', '137'), ('Vila do Conde', '8'), ('Maia', '119'), ('Penafiel', '7'), ('Vila Nova de Gaia', '83'), ('Portimão', '7'), ('Oliveira de Azeméis', '18'), ('Évora', '5')]
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ncgJrc/1).

---

The expression explained:

```
\b                      # a word boundary
(?P<city>               # a capturing group named "city"
    (?:[A-Za-zéÉã]+\s)+ # allowed characters for the cites,
                        # followed by a space
)
\D+                     # not digits
(?P<number>\d+)         # first digit after the city name
```

Comment: That really helped! I just need to add more allowed characters for the city names (Íâúôóç-). Thank you!